# Pythonic way results to <generator object <genexpr> at 0x106915f90>

Tags: python, for-loop, set

I'm trying to add keys and values into one set, but I'm wondering why this:

```
corpus = {"1.html": {"2.html", "3.html"}, "2.html":
 {"3.html"}, "3.html": {"2.html"}}

unique = set(val for each in corpus.values() for val in each)
for x in corpus.keys():
    unique.add(x)
```

results to this:`{'2.html', '1.html', '3.html'}`

but this:

```
corpus = {"1.html": {"2.html", "3.html"}, "2.html":
 {"3.html"}, "3.html": {"2.html"}}

unique = set(val for each in corpus.values() for val in each)
unique.add(x for x in corpus.keys())
```

results to this:
`{<generator object <genexpr> at 0x106915f90>, '3.html', '2.html'}`

Comment: Because in the second version, you add the generator `x for x in corpus.keys()` to the set and not `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[set.add](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.add) expects a single argument, so when passed a generator expression it adds it to the set.

To unpack the generator expression, pass it to [set.update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update), which expects an iterable.

```
>>> s = {x for x in 'abc'}
>>> s.update(x for x in 'def')
>>> s
{'e', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'b'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Solved the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

`x for x in corpus.keys()` is a generator expression, and will only generate on demand.

`set.add()` will add an item to the set, and it doesn't matter which type it is. You have to add each item individually, like you do in the first example.